# optimization of some numpy/scipy code

Tags: optimization, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to optimize some python code, which uses `scipy.optimize.root` for rootfinding.

cProfile tells me that most of the time the programm is evaluating the function called by `optimize.root`:
e.g. for a total execution time of 80s, 58s are spend on `lineSphericalDist` to which `fun` contributes 54s (and about 215 000 calls):

```
Fri Aug  8 21:09:32 2014    profile2

         12796193 function calls (12617458 primitive calls) in 82.707 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.005    0.005   82.710   82.710 BilliardsNumpyClass.py:6(<module>)
        1    0.033    0.033   64.155   64.155 BilliardsNumpyClass.py:446(traceAll)
      100    1.094    0.011   63.549    0.635 BilliardsNumpyClass.py:404(trace)
    91333    7.226    0.000   58.804    0.001 BilliardsNumpyClass.py:244(lineSphericalDist)
   214667   49.436    0.000   54.325    0.000 BilliardsNumpyClass.py:591(fun)
    ...
```

Here the optimize.root call somehwere in `trace`:

```
    ...
            res = optimize.root(self.lineSphericalDist, [tguess], args=(t0, a0), method='lm')
    ...
```

The function contains of some basic trigonometric functions:

```
    def lineSphericalDist(self, tt, t0, a0):
        x0,y0,vnn = self.fun(t0)[0:3]
        beta = np.pi + t0 + a0 - vnn

        l = np.sin(beta - t0)/np.sin(beta - tt)

        x2,y2 = self.fun(tt)[0:2]
        return np.sqrt(x0**2+y0**2)*l-np.sqrt(x2**2+y2**2)
```

In the easiest case fun is:

```
    def fun(self,t):
        return self.r*np.cos(t),self.r*np.sin(t),np.pi/2.,np.mod(t+np.pi/2., np.pi*2.)
```

**Is there a way to speed this up (tguess is already a pretty good starting value) ?** Am I doing something wrong? e.g. is it a good idea to return multiple values the way I do it in `fun` ?

Comment: the bottleneck in this case seems to be the function `trace()`, therefore you should find alternatives to `optimize.root()` in order to get a speed improvement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your `a0` and `t0` are not part of the optimization, you only optimize over `tt`. However, inside `lineSphericalDist`, you call self.fun(t0). You could precompute that quantity outside of lineSphericalDist, that would halve the number of calls to self.fun...

You could also compute `beta`, and `np.sin(beta - t0)`, and `np.sqrt(x0**2 + y0**2)` outside lineSphericalDist, leaving only the bits that really depend on `tt` inside lineSphericalDist.

Lastly, why does self.fun compute 4 values if only 3 or 2 are used? This is your bottleneck function, make it compute only what's strictly necessary...